# Which Windows component checks driver signature?

Tags: windows, certificate, driver, digital-signature

Which windows component (process, service, driver, etc.) is responsible for driver signature checking (according to driver signature enforcement policy) on OS Windows x64?

Answer (score 0):

the Windows Kernel which load the device drivers.